# cannot import certificate_transparency

Tags: python, python-2.7, aws-lambda, python-cryptography

Getting below error in AWS Lambda using when using python 2.7

`cannot import certificate_transparency`

When I hit the lambda API again the below error starts coming:

`cannot import retry`

I'm using below packages:

`oci==2.2.5`

`future==0.17.1`

`cffi==1.12.3`

In the analysis, it seems the issue is with the cryptography package used by OCI. I tried to explicitly install cryptography 2.4.2,but getting same error.

A help to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question with more detail error log ?

Comment: Does the same script work on your local computer?